# htaccess rewrited url and php GET method

Tags: php, .htaccess

How to manage the GET method if I have changed the URLs?

I changed the PHP webpages URL from

```
website.com/article.php?id=1&name=NewStory
```

to

```
website.com/article/1/NewStory
```

.htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) article.php?id=$1&name=$2 [NC,L]
```

Before, building the URL was easy because you add to the URL your info, like:

```
article.php?id=1&name=NewStory
```

Taking the info from URL using GET method was also easy, like:

```
$articleID = $_GET['id'];
$articleName = $_GET['name'];
```

Could you please help me with a solution for keeping the URLs as I have changed with the .htaccess file and manage the GET method?

How to take the info from a URL like this, using the GET method?

```
website.com/article/1/NewStory
```

How to write a URL to keep it as per the .htaccess file?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your new URL `/article/1/NewStory` is currently pointing to the `/article.php` file via `Multiviews` and not via the `RewriteRule`

To fix this , You need to disable `Multiviews` and remove the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f` condition as its checking for an existent PHP file to rewrite.

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) article.php?id=$1&name=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Hi @AmitThakur, Thank you for your message. Could you please let me know with your solutions, how to take info from URL using the GET method, and write a URL in PHP?

Comment: @Andrei  you can access `$_GET['id']; ` and `$_GET['name'];` on your `article.php`  file.